# Why do I get different number output with Group by clause

Tags: sql, impala

I have a source system where I get for example a count of ID of 2318.

I made two queries, 1 is showing only count of the IDs and a second one has a group by clause. But in the end the outcome is different.

**1. Query**

```
    SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT ID)
    FROM my_table fact
    JOIN d_time time ON ( time.time_5_min_utc = (fact.host_tlt_utc -(fact.host_tlt_utc % (300*1000))))
    WHERE fact.host_tlt_utc >= ${fromTimestamp}
      AND fact.host_tlt_utc < ${fromTimestamp}  + 86400000
      AND time.time_5_min_utc >= ${fromTimestamp} 
      AND time.time_5_min_utc < ${fromTimestamp}  + 86400000;
```

Output of this query is 2318

| COUNT(DISTINCT ID) |
| --- |
| 2318 |

**2. Query**

```
SELECT 
status,
COUNT(DISTINCT ID)
FROM my_table fact
JOIN d_time time ON ( time.time_5_min_utc = (fact.host_tlt_utc -(fact.host_tlt_utc % (300*1000))))
WHERE fact.host_tlt_utc >= ${fromTimestamp}
  AND fact.host_tlt_utc < ${fromTimestamp}  + 86400000
  AND time.time_5_min_utc >= ${fromTimestamp} 
  AND time.time_5_min_utc < ${fromTimestamp}  + 86400000
  group by status;
```

Output if I sum up all the lines is much higher.

| status | COUNT(DISTINCT ID) |
| --- | --- |
| Open | 1383 |
| In_Progress | 980 |
| Ready | 20 |

Is there any explanation why such different output is shown? I think in the end it should be the same.

Thank you.

Comment: Same ID can be found for different status values.

Comment: @jarlh Checked id and is not as far as I have seen.

Comment: `select id from ... group by id having count(distinct status) > 1` will tell you.

Comment: @jarlh you are right, there are duplicates. Thank you